# pass parameters from logic app email trigger to azure function http trigger issue

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a azure logic app that triggers when an email shows up, then I have that linked to a http triggered azure function.  I am trying to read a few parameters in the function, passed from the logic app.  can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

[image: screenshot of logic setup]

code in azure function

```
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = req.Query["name"];
        string attachmentName = req.Query["attachmentName"];
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);


        name = name ?? data?.name;
```

name gets populated correctly but attachmentName is ignored.  I think it has something to do with the last line of code. data.name.  I don't understand what that line is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the test, `req.Query` obtains parameters in the form of `<your-url>? parameter1 = value1&parameter2 = value2`. In other words, `req.Query` can only get the parameters in the `Get` request.

You are sending a post request, so using `req.Query` cannot get the parameters you want.

> I think it has something to do with the last line of code. data.name. I don't understand what that line is doing.

This code is to judge whether the name is empty, if it is empty, then name=data?name.

`req.Query` did not get the value of name, so this code gets the value of name from `data?.name`, so this is the reason why `name` has a value but `attachmentName` has no value in your result .

The correct code should look like this:

```
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];
            string attachmentName = req.Query["attachmentName"];
            
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            
            name = name ?? data?.name;
            attachmentName = attachmentName ?? data?.attachmentName;

            log.LogInformation(name);
            log.LogInformation(attachmentName);

            return new OkObjectResult(name);
        }
    }
```